# C# WPF MVVM Caliburm-micro Binding `GradientStops` dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I need to create component with dynamically created `LinearGradientBrush`.

What I've tried:

**View:**

```
<Grid.Background>
   <LinearGradientBrush  EndPoint="0.5,1"
                         MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" 
                         StartPoint="0.5,0" 
                         GradientStops="{Binding ColorsThresholds }">
   </LinearGradientBrush>
</Grid.Background>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel: Screen
{
    public BindableCollection<GradientStop> ColorsThresholds
    {
        get
        {
            return = GenerateRanges();
        }
    }
    private BindableCollection<GradientStop> GenerateRanges()
    {
        //Some generating stuff
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
         NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=> ColorsThresholds);
    }


}
```

`ColorsThresholds` is genrated well, but it is still not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GradientStops` is of type `GradientStopCollection` as you can see from [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationCore/R/0392ede480e9384d.html). Instead of `BindableCollection<GradientStop>` use a `GradientStopCollection`.